# C++ i can't find breakpoints that will stop the execution of the program when an alert is sent

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    //define TSH variable as a real number
    float TSH = 0.0;
    
    //Prompt the user to input TSH 
    cout<<"Input TSH value";       
    //Read TSH value 
    cin >> TSH;
    if(TSH > 5.0){
        cout << "Alert: Patient may have Hyperthyroidism";      
    }else if (TSH < 0.5){
        cout << "Alert: Patient may have Hyperthyroidism";
    }else{
        cout << "Thyroid function is normal";}
           
        return 0;   
    }
}
```

can't exactly find the breakpoints.

Comment: Breakpoints are a tool of the debugger. Which debugger are you using? Are you using an IDE? Most IDEs I know allow you to set a breakpoint simply by clicking the line you wish to stop at.

Comment: Also, your function does not return anything if you enter a 'Warning value'. Your compiler should be warning you about that.

Comment: I'm using Dev c++

Comment: @RefugnicEternium _"...The body of the `main` function does not need to contain the return statement: if control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;...."_  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function

Comment: @RichardCritten Thank you for educating me about this. I still think that a function returning anything (even if it is the main function) should have an explicit return code.

Comment: Sir can i email you privately?

Comment: No, you can't. I just looked at Dev C++ (using QtCreator myself). But have you tried clicking in that small grey bar next to the line of code you wish to set the breakpoint to? Did a red dot appear? If so, you have found the breakpoints.

Comment: Yeah does it highlights the line of code?

Comment: Yes, in bright red judging from the image I am seeing. Now, if you run the program in 'Debugger mode', code execution will stop at that line.